# Liferay Top Level Friendly URL

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Is there a way to create / process friendly URLs in liferay like this?

```
http://myserver.com/JonDoe
```

... where John Doe is the name of a clients whose data should be displayed.

**A little more detail:**

I am not talking about getting rid of the "web" or "group" for friendly urls, I am taking about having a friendly url right after the first "/".

We want to create URLs in the form of http://server/ClientName where ClientName resolves to the name of a Client. This is an issue since normally liferay would expect a friendly URL after the first "/". So we ned to intercept that somehow.

**The process should be like this (pseudo code):**

1) inspect values after first "/"

2) If value after "/" is the name of a client, send user to client display page and display client information

3) If there is no client with the given name, interpret it as friendly url and do normal liferay behaviour.

Is there a way to do this in liferay ?

Comment: Could you add some more details? Do you need a friendly URL for a specific page - that is possible, as Olaf already explains? Or do you want to have a friendly URL for a specific content on a page. In that case it it only possible to have something like `http://myserver.com/page/-/myPortlet/JonDoe` - or you patch Liferay to match your use case, which is possible as well.

Comment: Hi Tobias, the client wants to enter a URL in the format http//server/ClientName which should take all the data of the client and display it. This is a problem since liferay will try to resolve a site named "ClientName". So I need to add some logic that tries to query a client with Clientname and if it finds that client it will transport the user to a client display page. If it doesnt find the client it will interpret the string as a friendly url and forward the user there (standard liferay behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to get rid of the /web/ or /group/ parts of the URLs? This is possible with proper configuration of the virtual host - you'll map the site to the domain name, then you have total freedom to name the pages, even hierarchically (e.g. /JonDoe/home)

So far this was simple configuration. If you want /JonDoe to point to *another site* than /JoeShmoe (e.g. *just* get rid of /web/ or /group/), you'll have to dig deeper and write quite some customization plugins that change the name resolving (and generation of URLs)

Comment: Hi Olaf, I think the Clients Request is pretty costly because it would require differentiating between actual pages /my-page and company names /company-name . I will think about it a little more ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have **one** URL for a page, you can just set the *friendly URL* for that page (see Olafs remark about virtual hosts as well)

If you want to have a **limited** set of URLs for one page, you can create a page of type *Link to Page* for each URL and select the original page. To identify the current URL when rendering you portlet you can use `PortalUtil.getCurrentURL(renderRequest)`

If you want to have **many** URLs for one page you could use a `FriendlyUrlMapper`, which allows URLs like `http://myserver.com/page/-/myPortlet/JonDoe`.

If you want to have **many "root" URLs** (i mean without the `/page/-/myPortlet` part), you will have to create an Liferay EXT plugin, extend `com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl` and overwrite `getPortletFriendlyURLMapperLayoutQueryStringComposite`. I've done the same by implementing a strategy that checks if a page exists for a specific given URL and otherwise uses the URL as parameter for a FriendlyURLMapper.